# PHP/JAVA Bridge via Tomcat main(): Failed opening required 'http://localhost:8080/JavaBridge/java/Java.inc'

Tags: java, php, laravel, laravel-5, php-java-bridge

I'm trying to implement a PHP/JAVA bridge from my Laravel 5 application.

I keep getting this message however:

main(): Failed opening required 'http://localhost:8080/JavaBridge/java/Java.inc' (include_path='/home/vagrant/sites/new_metinet/vendor/phpunit/php-text-template:/home/vagrant/sites/new_metinet/vendor/phpunit/php-timer:/home/vagrant/sites/new_metinet/vendor/phpunit/php-file-iterator:.:/usr/share/php:/usr/share/pear')

main(): Failed opening required 'http://127.0.0.1:8080/JavaBridge/java/Java.inc' (include_path='/home/vagrant/sites/new_metinet/vendor/phpunit/php-text-template:/home/vagrant/sites/new_metinet/vendor/phpunit/php-timer:/home/vagrant/sites/new_metinet/vendor/phpunit/php-file-iterator:.:/usr/share/php:/usr/share/pear')

This is the php code calling the Java Bridge

```
<?php namespace App\Services\JavaBridge;

require_once("http://localhost:8080/JavaBridge/java/Java.inc");

class JavaRepository {

    public function test() {

        try {

            /* invoke java.lang.System.getProperties() */
            $props = java("java.lang.System")->getProperties();

            /* convert the result object into a PHP array */
            $array = java_values($props);
            foreach($array as $k=>$v) {
                echo "$k=>$v"; echo "<br>\n";
            }
            echo "<br>\n";

            /* create a Java object from the PHP object */
            $javaObject = java_closure(new JavaClass());
            echo "PHP says that Java says: "; echo $javaObject;  echo "<br>\n";
            echo "<br>\n";


            echo java("php.java.bridge.Util")->VERSION; echo "<br>\n";

        } catch (JavaException $ex) {

            echo "An exception occured: "; echo $ex; echo "<br>\n";

        }
    }

}

/* create a PHP class which implements the Java toString() method */
class JavaClass {
    function toString() { return "hello PHP from Java!"; }
}
```

I've done:

- chmod all directories
- used localhost & 127.0.0.1
- allowed_url_include = on

Can anyone help please?

Comment: Is that URL locally accesible, what does `curl -I http://localhost:8080/JavaBridge/java/Java.inc` print out?

Comment: I've just had a brainwave that i'm running laravel from homestead on a vagrant box...so I can't access the localhost:8080 tomcat.

So next question...how do I install Java on homestead?

Comment: This article is pretty comprehensive https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-install-apache-tomcat-7-on-ubuntu-14-04-via-apt-get. You'll have to `ssh` into the Vagrant box and run the command there of course.

Comment: FYI Curl print out was:

:curl {@10 ▼
  url: "http://localhost:8080/JavaBridge/java/Java.inc"
  content_type: null
  http_code: 0
  header_size: 0
  request_size: 0
  filetime: 0
  ssl_verify_result: 0
  redirect_count: 0
  total_time: 0.0
  namelookup_time: 0.0
  connect_time: 0.0
  pretransfer_time: 0.0
  size_upload: 0.0
  size_download: 0.0
  speed_download: 0.0
  speed_upload: 0.0
  download_content_length: -1.0
  upload_content_length: -1.0
  starttransfer_time: 0.0
  redirect_time: 0.0
  redirect_url: ""
  primary_ip: ""
  certinfo: []
  primary_port: 0
  local_ip: ""
  local_port: 0
}

Comment: Thanks for the link to digital ocean Bogdan  - fantastic help.

Answer (score 0):

So, I got the answer to this with the help of Bogdan.

I was running my Laravel5 app via homestead, so the localhost I was hitting via the browser was not actually accessible from vagrant.

So I had to install tomcat on my vagrant box which I did via this article https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-install-apache-tomcat-7-on-ubuntu-14-04-via-apt-get (credit: Bogdan).

However, I did have trouble uploading the JAVA Bridge up to that tomcat setup, so I did have to recreate the tomcat setup I have on my computer on the homestead environment in the same way that you would host your website files. Not great admittedly, but I don't like to hang around!

The article was great however, because it helped install all the required associated packages Tomcat needs..such as Java.

Basically there is a better way, but this works. Thanks Bogdan!